# How to resume the last activity after the user closed Android kivy app?

Tags: python, android, kivy

I created a calculator with memory function, Answer history and Other Functions that need to remain stored even if the user completely closed the.

Kivy has an **on_pause** and **on_resume** methods of the main app class that can be use to resume the app if suspended and not close.

Is there a way the user can resume to recent activities if the app is closed?

Please help me, thanks..

Comment: You're looking at cache files, or long term storage. As the app memory will clear once the app gets closed.

Comment: @Torxed   How do i implement this in the kivy app?

Comment: We're not a coding service. And this isn't Kivy specific.

Comment: One way is to use an app specific `Config`. Have a look at [Kivy Config](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/config.html#local-configuration).

Comment: You can save it in json file

Comment: @JohnAnderson i don't seems to understand how this can be done using an app specific config, can you please write a snippet?

Comment: @Pikro, how can i load the file after it has been saved?

Comment: The [application configuration](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#application-configuration) provides a simple example. The `.ini` file for your `App` is loaded automatically, and you can write information to it by using `Config.set()` and `Config.write()`. And you can get information from it using `Config.get()`

Comment: @JohnAnderson ok thanks! I later saved it in json file with the help of Pikro answer and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Json file

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore('file name.json')

# put some values
store.put('tito', name='Mathieu', org='kivy')
store.put('tshirtman', name='Gabriel', age=27)

# using the same index key erases all previously added key-value pairs
store.put('tito', name='Mathieu', age=30)

# get a value using a index key and key
print('tito is', store.get('tito')['age'])

# or guess the key/entry for a part of the key
for item in store.find(name='Gabriel'):
    print('tshirtmans index key is', item[0])
    print('his key value pairs are', str(item[1]))
```

[More information](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.storage.html)